# Save regular expression result in variable

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, variables

I would like to split a string into separated, single strings and save each in a new variable. That's the use case:

- Direct user input with `BC1 = input("BC1: ")` in the following format: `'17899792270101010000000000', '17899792270102010000000000', '17899792270103010000000000'`
- Now I want each number - and just the number in a single variable:

  ```
  a = 17899792270101010000000000
  b = 17899792270102010000000000
  c = 17899792270103010000000000
  ```

How to realise that in python 3?

Sadly I'm not able to create a suitable regular expression for it and neither a way to save string parts in separate variables. I hope someone of you could help me. 
Thanks already in advance!

Comment: Would you say this is a csv format? If it is, why not use the csv module?

Comment: Look at re.match - it returns matched parts of your regexp, specified by putting ( ) around the part.

Comment: the input you give is not a string format but a tuple of strings...

Comment: Someone will probably come along and answer this anyway, but for future reference, you can increase your chances of getting quality help by showing that you've put some effort into it yourself. Show what code you've tried, and describe how the output differs from what you're expecting.

Comment: Reut: No, it's not about csv, I get it with a user input and want save it in a variable for further use of the value
barny: thanks, but how to save the result splitted in a variable then?

Beauvel: ok?

Comment: @glibdud: I don't see a sense in showing my wrong regular expression - I know it's wrong.
And I don't know a way to save the result of a re function in separate variables, I didn't find a function to do this. How should I show that in the main question?
I put effort in it, believe me.. In the tutorials there are just examples who don't fit to my problem and in no tutorial I have seen a way to save the relevant strings in variables.

Comment: People are volunteering their time here, and you'll find that the amount of time they're willing to put into helping you is correlated to the amount of work you've shown you've put into it yourself. Plus, if you show your failed attempt, someone can explain *why* it's wrong and how to fix it (or whether it's better to go in a completely different direction).

Comment: And for what it's worth, the problem as presented doesn't require `re` or `csv` or any other module. (Hint: [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int))

Comment: @glibud: The thing is, that I know these functions already out of the tutorials I read, but I don't know the right regular expression to get these 3 numbers and I don't know how to get these separated into variables...

To the other thing, you don't need to help me if you don't want to or if the question is not qualified enough for you. I know these kind of guys already who prefer to criticize instead of simply to help.
I just reduced the question to the necessary information.

Comment: Thanks a lot to Foryah and Matthias, both solutions are great.

@glibud: Due to the help of these guys I can continue now, analyze their solutions, check what was wrong with mine and right with theirs. I can continue scripting and learning without wasting endless time. And I'm sure these guys didn't lose much time either with that little problem as they are professionals. That's how support works!

That's much more friendly and useful as these useless answers like.. ah whatever ;)

Comment: @Helle Sorry if you took my recommendations as criticism. I was simply trying to share my experiences here and what I've learned since I asked my first (low quality!) questions. Happy coding.

Comment: @gilbdud: It's ok, I know your point of view. It just sounded like you thought that I didn't put effort at all and that this question could be easily answered directly by google.
Anyway, happy coding too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
import re

input = "'17899792270101010000000000', '17899792270102010000000000', '17899792270103010000000000'"

 matches = re.findall('(\d+)', input)
 # matches = ['17899792270101010000000000', '17899792270102010000000000', '17899792270103010000000000']

 a, b, c = re.findall('(\d+)', input)
 # a = '17899792270101010000000000'
 # b = '17899792270102010000000000'
 # c = '17899792270103010000000000'
```

edit: 
If you want `int` not `str`, you can `map(int, matches)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will adjust that solution for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this should do the trick

```
BC1 = input("BC1: ")
numbers = [int(x.strip(' \'')) for x in BC1.split(',')]
```

And now your desired numbers are

```
numbers[0] == a # 17899792270101010000000000
numbers[1] == b # 17899792270102010000000000
numbers[2] == c # 17899792270103010000000000
```

- The [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function creates an array of your numbers, but includes the spaces and the quotes.

  `["'17899792270101010000000000'", " '17899792270102010000000000'", " '17899792270103010000000000'"]`
- The [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) function gets rid of the spaces and the quotes

  `['17899792270101010000000000', '17899792270102010000000000', '17899792270103010000000000']`
- The [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function parses the strings into an integer (number)

  `[17899792270101010000000000, 17899792270102010000000000, 17899792270103010000000000]`

However, this requires the user to follow the format you specified. [Foryah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43095545/5272567) is more robust to different input formats.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, this suits exactly to the case I mentioned. 
I also will check Foryah's answer.

Answer (score 0):

if it's already "format" at the input :

```
>>> BC1 = input("BC1: ")
BC1: '17899792270101010000000000', '17899792270102010000000000', '17899792270103010000000000'
>>> a=int(BC1[0])
>>> b=int(BC1[1])
>>> c=int(BC1[2])
>>> a
17899792270101010000000000
>>> b
17899792270102010000000000
>>> c
17899792270103010000000000
```